# Animate with a negative scrollTop/scrollLeft value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 sections surrounding the absolute positioned section and need to be able to click the list items to animate to them. This works fine for two of sections but for the section with a left: -100 and the right: -300 doesn't animate. Is there a way to make scrollTop and Left work with a negative value?

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/oLzppt3o/)

```
$('#hilolink').click(function() {
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollLeft: $('#hiLo').offset().left
    }, 500);
});
$('.hiloback').click(function() {
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollLeft: $('#allGames').offset().left
    }, 500);
});
$('#simonSays').click(function() {
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#simon').offset().top
    }, 500);
});
$('.simonback').click(function() {
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#allGames').offset().top
    }, 500);
});
$('#rock').click(function() {
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#rockPaper').offset().top
    }, 500);
});
$('.rockback').click(function() {
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#allGames').offset().top
    }, 500);
});
$('#dance').click(function() {
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollLeft: $('#danceDance').offset().left
    }, 500);
});
$('.rockback').click(function() {
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollLeft: $('#allGames').offset().left
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: maybe using coordonates and css transition ? https://jsfiddle.net/oLzppt3o/1/

Comment: @GCyrillus I'd like to keep the animation looking the same for each direction and I want it to appear like the navigation page is surrounded by minigames on each side.

Answer (score 0):

According to this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrollleft.asp you can't have negative values in either scrollLeft or scrollRight:

> If the number is a negative value, the number is set to "0"

But you can try placing your elements with a sufficient added offset (making sure none of them is positioned in a negative offset) and define a new origin which would be considered as your 0,0, let say 1000,1000. 
Upon initialization, reset your scroll offset to this origin, and do all your scrolling relative to that new origin.